# Is it possible to set only a part of CMake project build with debug info and others building in release mode?

Tags: c++, cmake

If I have a C++ CMake project with some submodules.
Can I just build one or some submodules in Debug mode and let the main project and other submodule compile in Release mode?
If possible, what should I do in CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I don't know if it's *possible*, but it *is* highly likely to give you silent ODR errors.

Comment: The fact that you're libraries are in git submodules is irrelevant. I'd remove the "git" tag. It depends a lot on your code and your CMakeLists. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think this is really a duplicate of [How can I compose separate git+CMake projects together for ease of building while allowing mixed build configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76146612/11107541), (but there's no accepted or upvoted answer there yet). Can you check out the answers there and see if one answers your question here? If so, please give it an upvote.