# VScode - How to share a single components folder in a Multi-root workspace, across multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, project, workspace

sorry for the noob question, vscode is so confusing to get around
for espressif ESP32 projects, all sharing the same 'components'
trying NOT to duplicate (copy/paste) in every project the same git repository as 'components'

trying to share a single components folder in a Multi-root workspace
have 3 project folders in the root, A, B, C
and also the components folder
how do you specify for project B to use the .h files in the root 'components' ?

```
Root
   -components
     --library
       ---src (all the c, h shared libraries)
   -A
   -B
     --main
       ---CMakeLists.txt
   -C
```

assuming here that the CMakeLists.txt in Project B / main, references the 'components' folder in the root ?

idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
INCLUDE_DIRS "")

INCLUDE_DIRS "" - how do you reference the root of the Multi-root workspace ?

or is this done in the multi-root.code-workspace file ?

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "components"
        },
        {
            "path": "A"
        },
        {
            "path": "B"
        },
        {
            "path": "B"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

NOTE, i also have in the Multi-root workspace root, the settings.json
in here i have :
"cmake.sourceDirectory": "/home/abc/def/Root/components/library"

but this does not find the files in the sub folder 'src'

Comment: how would you do it if you did not use VSC

Comment: why not just `add_subdirectory` it with a relative path to the components folder in each project? Or build it as its own project and then `export` and `include` the exported targets file in each project? Why are you looking to VS Code or something that CMake can already do?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76146612/11107541 and my answer there. If that answers your question, let's close this as a duplicate. if it doesn't answer your question, edit your question post to explain why.