# How can I avoid target name clashes when add_subdirectory()ing both the mainstream and a fork of a repository?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, dynamic-linking

For a good reason, I am attempting to use `add_subdirectory()` on both a fork of a repository and the mainstream repository, and both `add_library()` a library with the same name.
I will only privately link these two resulting libraries on 2 different other library targets, that will be `dlopen()`ed by the main target, but never linked directly.

What is the best way to do this? Is there anything like *namespaces* that I could run the `add_subdirectory()` calls in to not make the library names collide?

Comment: You could build those libs separately, install them together with cmake configuration scripts into differend directories. As long as the configuration scripts don't create global import libraries, you should be able to use those as long as none of the `find_package` uses for importing the installed libs is in the same or an ancestor cmake source directory of the other. But creating 2 cmake targets of the same name afaik that's impossible; after all which one of the targets should be build for `cmake --build ... --target the_duplicated_target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to do this?

At the time of this writing? Either patch the target names to prevent name collisions (if you want to continue `add_subdirectory`ing them), or drop the `add_subdirectory` approach and use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) to configure, build, and install, and then add the installed targets to your project configuration as [imported libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries), which allows you to control the target name.

> Is there anything like namespaces that I could run the add_subdirectory() calls in to not make the library names collide?

Not at the time of this writing. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22687 and https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16414.

---

Related: [How can I avoid target name collisions when using CMake FetchContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70381809/11107541).