# Link to all subtargets of the same CMake namespace

Tags: cmake

While using **CMake** and *namespaced* targets using the '**packagename::subtarget**' syntax is standard practice these days, I was wondering if the namespace is somehow useful to navigate, or more specifically: bundle *all* targets and link to *all* of them in one fell swoop.

True navigation of namespaces in CMake implies the support of nested namespaces and some sort of x-path syntax - that's definitely not possible.

But I was wondering if something simple like ***bundle all*** of the sub-targets can be done, for example, is it possible to wrap something like..

```
target_link_libraries(target foo::bar)
target_link_libraries(target foo::bas)    
target_link_libraries(target foo::bay)
...
target_link_libraries(target foo::baz)
```

..into something shorter like..

```
target_link_libraries(target foo::*)
```

.. without having to build a fake target or iterate through a known list of the targets? In many cases that should just work when linking to an external package - mostly, because there might be cases where sibling targets in the same namespace actually contain different versions of the same interface - one may wonder if that's good practice but that's another story.

I haven't seen anything that points to this in the documentation but perhaps there is some way to do it?

Comment: "I was wondering if the namespace is somehow useful to navigate" - No, what you name as "namespace" is just a regular part of a target name. Well, there is actually one specific of a namespace which is concerned by CMake (and which is really useful). If you link `target_link_libraries(target foo)` and CMake doesn't find `foo` target, then it silently passes `-lfoo` to the linker. But if you link `target_link_libraries(target foo::bar)` and `foo::bar` target does not exist, then CMake emits the error. But otherwise CMake doesn't interpret a namespace in a specific way.

Comment: I know no way for easy access all targets in a namespace. And I found a little usefulness in that: If the package's maintainer think that linkage with all project's targets - `foo::bar`, `foo::bas`, ... - to be useful scenario, then it could easily provide an INTERFACE library which explicitly links to all such targets. Otherwise, if `foo::` namespace contains both static and shared libraries (which is quite common, actually), then possibility to link with `foo::*` would only confuse a project's user.

Comment: With the current state of affairs, I completely agree with the points you make! A case could be made to extend the 'namespace::' idiom and have a matching approach to selecting the targets.. would still depend on the publisher of the package providing the namespace structuring, except in the simplest case: 'select all the targets'. The error reporting feature is nice, but I can hardly imagine it was the only reason to bring that into the fold.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/75205569/11107541

Comment: Thanks for the link to project level namespaces.. seems to think along the same lines. Thanks.